# How can my Chrome extension listen for the Compose window opening in Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension for Gmail that modifies the Compose window. It works fine whenever I refresh the page and open the Compose window after the page refresh, but the next time I open the Compose window (without the Gmail refresh), the content script fails to load. My Content script begins like this:

updateContent.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addUpdateButton, true);

addUpdateButton();

.
.
.
```

Clearly, listening for DOMContentLoaded isn't what I want, so what do I listen for? The relevant part of my manifest looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{"run_at": "document_end",
 "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/mail/*"],
 "js": ["updateContent.js", "colorHeaders.js", "renderContent.js", "sendOptions.js", 
 "base64.js", "jsaes.js"]
}
],
```

Comment: Use a library like [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js) or observe DOM using MutationObserver yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following code to one of my content scripts:

```
            // Listen for Compose button-click
        var composeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3');
        composeButton[0].addEventListener("click", addUpdateButton);
```

I added the code at the bottom of a function that only gets called after the page has finished loading (I check every 200 msec to see if loading has completed).